# Touch Pad problems in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: touchpad, dell, inspiron

I have a Dell Inspiron 15-3531 using Ubuntu 16.04 for a couple months and when I use the touch pad it just turns crazy the most of time, it shiver and moves to other places, since I mostly use a mouse never got annoyed but now I would want to fix it. I had a windows partition and I removed it, but when I did it some troubles happened and i had to install ubuntu more than three times...maybe that's the deal.

I would be really grateful if somebody help me, thanks.

This is the output of the properties from my touchpad, I've been changing the "Synaptics finger" field to adjust sensitivity but still shaking, at least it does not fly to my right down corner as it used to. But now it take as secondary when I scroll a lot of times, I need to know what does the numbers in "Synaptics finger" means, only know that when it increases the force needed to use the touchpad have to increase too.

```
luismario@luismarioinspiron:~$ xinput --watch-props 11
Device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad':
    Device Enabled (139):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (141): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (265): 1
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (266):   2.500000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (267):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (268):    12.500000
    Synaptics Edges (269):  1576, 5366, 1353, 4499
    Synaptics Finger (270): 40, 55, 100
    Synaptics Tap Time (271):   180
    Synaptics Tap Move (272):   251
    Synaptics Tap Durations (273):  180, 100, 100
    Synaptics ClickPad (274):   0
    Synaptics Middle Button Timeout (275):  75
    Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure (276):    282
    Synaptics Two-Finger Width (277):   7
    Synaptics Scrolling Distance (278): -114, -114
    Synaptics Edge Scrolling (279): 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling (280):   1, 1
    Synaptics Move Speed (281): 1.000000, 1.750000, 0.034934, 0.000000
    Synaptics Off (282):    2
    Synaptics Locked Drags (283):   0
    Synaptics Locked Drags Timeout (284):   5000
    Synaptics Tap Action (285): 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0
    Synaptics Click Action (286):   1, 1, 0
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling (287): 0
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling Distance (288):    0.100000
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling Trigger (289): 0
    Synaptics Circular Pad (290):   0
    Synaptics Palm Detection (291): 0
    Synaptics Palm Dimensions (292):    10, 200
    Synaptics Coasting Speed (293): 20.000000, 50.000000
    Synaptics Pressure Motion (294):    30, 160
    Synaptics Pressure Motion Factor (295): 1.000000, 1.000000
    Synaptics Resolution Detect (296):  1
    Synaptics Grab Event Device (297):  0
    Synaptics Gestures (298):   1
    Synaptics Capabilities (299):   1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
    Synaptics Pad Resolution (300): 68, 44
    Synaptics Area (301):   0, 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Noise Cancellation (302): 8, 8
    Device Product ID (259):    2, 7
    Device Node (260):  "/dev/input/event5"
Property 'Synaptics Off' changed.
    Synaptics Off (282):    0
```

Comment: Did the touch pad work in Windows?  There is some basic touchpad troubleshooting info [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad).  Please edit your question to show the output of `xinput list`.

Comment: ooh and the pointer get craizier when my finger reach the edges of my touch pad

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is helpful, but here are the results from the touchpad on my Dell Latitude E6420:

```
user@computer:~$ xinput --watch-props 12
Device 'AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint TouchPad':
Device Enabled (139):   1
Coordinate Transformation Matrix (141): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
Device Accel Profile (262): 1
Device Accel Constant Deceleration (263):   2.500000
Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (264):   1.000000
Device Accel Velocity Scaling (265):    12.500000
Synaptics Edges (266):  300, 1700, 210, 1190
Synaptics Finger (267): 12, 15, 0
Synaptics Tap Time (268):   180
Synaptics Tap Move (269):   107
Synaptics Tap Durations (270):  180, 100, 100
Synaptics ClickPad (271):   0
Synaptics Middle Button Timeout (272):  75
Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure (273):    141
Synaptics Two-Finger Width (274):   7
Synaptics Scrolling Distance (275): 48, 48
Synaptics Edge Scrolling (276): 0, 0, 0
Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling (277):   1, 1
Synaptics Move Speed (278): 1.000000, 1.750000, 0.081934, 0.000000
Synaptics Off (279):    2
Synaptics Locked Drags (280):   0
Synaptics Locked Drags Timeout (281):   5000
Synaptics Tap Action (282): 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0
Synaptics Click Action (283):   1, 1, 0
Synaptics Circular Scrolling (284): 0
Synaptics Circular Scrolling Distance (285):    0.100000
Synaptics Circular Scrolling Trigger (286): 0
Synaptics Circular Pad (287):   0
Synaptics Palm Detection (288): 0
Synaptics Palm Dimensions (289):    10, 100
Synaptics Coasting Speed (290): 20.000000, 50.000000
Synaptics Pressure Motion (291):    15, 80
Synaptics Pressure Motion Factor (292): 1.000000, 1.000000
Synaptics Resolution Detect (293):  1
Synaptics Grab Event Device (294):  0
Synaptics Gestures (295):   1
Synaptics Capabilities (296):   1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0
Synaptics Pad Resolution (297): 1, 1
Synaptics Area (298):   0, 0, 0, 0
Synaptics Noise Cancellation (299): 12, 12
Device Product ID (257):    2, 8
Device Node (258):  "/dev/input/event7"

Property 'Synaptics Off' changed.
Synaptics Off (279):    0
```

You didn't mention if the touchpad worked properly in Windows.  If you haven't yet checked, then you should probably check that to rule out a hardware problem.  If it works fine in Windows, then I suppose you should tinker with the parameters.  If you find something that works, please answer your own question and accept the answer, to help people in the future.  Good luck.

Comment: I have no longer the windows partition but it worked fine there when I had. Now I will check and compare my parameters and yours, thanks! ...by the moment.